# Some Examples From Ben-Gan Why need "AS"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT MIN(col1) AS start_range, MAX(col1) AS end_range 
FROM (SELECT col1, 
        (
        SELECT MIN(B.col1) 
         FROM dbo.T1 AS B 
         WHERE B.col1 >= A.col1 
           AND NOT EXISTS 
             (SELECT * 
              FROM dbo.T1 AS C 
              WHERE C.col1 = B.col1 + 1)
        ) AS grp
      FROM dbo.T1 AS A) AS jh 
GROUP BY grp;
```

Why there would be error if I delete "AS jh"? And why I need same "AS grp". (Not same because I group by) but I can`t delete it. In second code no such "AS".

```
SELECT col1, 
  (SELECT MIN(B.col1) 
    FROM dbo.T1 AS B 
    WHERE B.col1 >= A.col1 
      -- is this row the last in its group? 
      AND NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM dbo.T1 AS C 
         WHERE C.col1 = B.col1 + 1))  FROM dbo.T1 AS A;
```

And third code:

```
SELECT MIN(col1) AS start_range, MAX(col1) AS end_range 
FROM (SELECT col1,  
        -- the difference is constant and unique per island 
        col1 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS grp 
      FROM dbo.T1) AS D 
GROUP BY grp;
```

How it works? It shows the same result as first code.
I understand second and fourth code. But I can`t really understand third. And my understanding of first is half.
How that (third) works?
Fourth:

```
SELECT col1, col1 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS diff 
FROM dbo.T1;
```

Answer (score 6):

First code: the inline select returns a result set = requires an alias

Second code

- the EXISTS is a correlated subquery to do a semi-join. No result set
- it returns a scalar value (not a result set) - no alias needed (but no column name then)

Third code:

- Uses ROW_NUMBER() which did not exist before SQL server 2005
- alias needed because it returns a result set

Not sure what you mean after that...

Comment: Thanks. I think there is join between min and max in first and third code. I can`t plus you because of my reputation. But thanks, gbn.

Comment: I still can`t understand why third code show this results. I need results like in first code and third code shows them. How third code works?

Comment: I understood third code. It works the same like first because of joiun, selfjoin

Comment: "alias needed because it returns a result set" Where can I read more about that?

Comment: Why second is result set as opposed to first?

Comment: @user2377214: not sure it is documented. It just appears to be a rule I've spotted

Comment: Its here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx Thanks to @AaronBertrand for this